# Draw high res animations with high frame rate on Android

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, canvas

I've got 30+ single bitmaps (320x240 pixels) that I would like to display one after another in full screen on Android devices resulting in an animation. Currently I implemented the animation using an ImageView and a Timer that sets the next frame and then sends a message that will apply the next frame. The resulting frame rate is very low: < 2 fps.

*The timer:*

```
animationTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Drawable frame = getNextFrame();
            if (frame != null) {
                Message message = animationFrameHandler.obtainMessage(1, frame);
                animationFrameHandler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }, 0, (int) (1000.0d / fps));
```

*The handler:*

```
final Handler animationFrameHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        setImageDrawable((Drawable) message.obj);
    }
};
```

Since I want to achieve frame rates up to 30 fps I have to make use of another mechanism and heard of **Canvas.drawBitmapMesh()** and **OpenGL**.

If possible I would like to avoid using OpenGL.

Thank you very sharing your experiences!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My now working approach is the following:

Before starting the animation, load every frame into a `List<Bitmap>`. Important: Call `System.gc()` if you're getting `OutOfMemoryError`s – that really helps loading more bitmaps into the memory. Then have a thread running that posts the next frame to a View instance that then update it's canvas.

**Loading the frames and starting the animation**

```
// Loading the frames before starting the animation
List<Bitmap> frames = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    // Load next frame (e. g. from drawable or assets folder)
    frames.add(...);
    // Do garbage collection every 3rd frame; really helps loading all frames into memory
    if (i %% 3 == 0) {
        System.gc();
    }
}

// Start animation
frameIndex = 0;
animationThread.start();
```

**Thread that applies the next frame**

```
private final class AnimationThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            // Post next frame to be displayed
            animationView.postFrame(frames.get(frameIndex));

            // Apply next frame (restart if last frame has reached)
            frameIndex++;
            if (frameIndex >= frames.size()) {
                frameIndex = 0;
            }

            try {
                sleep(33); // delay between frames in msec (33 msec mean 30 fps)
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The animation view**

```
class AnimationView extends View {
    Bitmap frame = null;

    public void postFrame(Bitmap frame) {
        Message message = frameHandler.obtainMessage(0, frame);
        frameHandler.sendMessage(message);
    }

    protected final Handler frameHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            if (message.obj != null) {
                frame = (Bitmap) message.obj;
            } else {
                frame = null;
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (frame == null) return;
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawBitmap(frame, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to "have a timer running that posts the next frame to a View instance",can you give a more detail thank you

Comment: Hello pengwang, I updated my answer to give more insights on my approach. Feel free to ask if there are still things unclear.

Comment: Hi Lars Blumberg. It throws me out of memory exception.           How I am adding bitmap to list as below.                                                                                 int[] splashdrawables={R.drawable.splashframe1,R.drawable.splashframe2.....};                               Drawable drawable=getResources().getDrawable(splashdrawables[i]);
     frames.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888));

Comment: Dear Sandy, please create a new StackOverflow question for that. So more people can analyze your problem. Feel free to link to my answer here when publishing your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the FrameAnimation class; http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation to do frame animation with Androids animation.

Though that might still be too slow.

The other alternative if you don't want to use OpenGL ES is to draw to the Canvas as you've mentioned. But just use .drawBitmap, not the drawBitmapMesh. Create a SurfaceView, which has a thread, that thread should draw on your Canvas at whatever interval you want.

It's pretty straightforward, just read the Android docs, the information is all there.

Comment: Indeed the FrameAnimation is too slow - it shows the same speed as my implementation does. Since I have to follow some particular rules for how to repeat the frames I made my own implementation. I'll look into the SurfaceView/.drawBitmap combination and will give feedback here. Thank you so far!

Comment: Thanks C0deAttack, studying the page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html#on-surfaceview (On a SurfaceView) helped me implementing a thread drawing the next frame in order to achieve an animation using a SurfaceView.

Comment: Unfortunately a transparent SurfaceView can not be layered over another SurfaceView that is being used for the camera preview ''getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS'' Said this, I am now using a View only that is being updated by a message being sent from a thread delivering the animation graphics. Unfortunately this does not give the desired performance, frame rates > 10 fps are hardly to achieve on low budget Android devices. So I will have to dive into OpenGL the next days. Thanks for every offered help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll let someone else go into the best way of doing this but one thing that immediately jumps to mind from your post that isn't helping is using TimerTask is a terrible way to do this and is not meant for animation.

Comment: You're right! For my test an how to do animations it was just enough. As I mentioned here, FrameAnimation isn't faster and doesn't allow you to say from which frame to loop, so using a TimerTask was just convenient for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't help with performance, but if those bitmaps are resources you might want to consider using an `AnimationDrawable`. If not, try to extend `Drawable` and implement the `Animatable` interface. Views already have built-in support for animating drawables, no need to use a handler for that.

One way to improve performance might be to match the bit-depth of the drawables to those of your current window. Romain Guy did a keynote on this and animations in general once: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duefsFTJXzc

Comment: You're right, using AnimationDrawable is as slow as my implementation. I will have a look onto the keynote. Thank you so far!