# Is drawing a fullscreen single frame animation using OpenGL feasible on Android?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

Currently I am displaying a single frame animation in full screen on a SurfaceView using a Timer and `Canvas.onDraw()` / `canvas.drawBitmap`. Every frame has a resolution of 480x320 pixels and will be stretched at drawing time to the screen resolution. This works quiet well on faster devices, achieving frame rates up to 15 fps. The problem is that I have to load every frame (the animation consists of 30 single frames that loop) before the animation starts since the animation will be displayed with a high frame rate. Given the small heap space for Android processes of usually 16 MB most of my testing devices are not capable of preloading all 30 frames into the memory so I am thinking to use OpenGL instead. As I read OpenGLs memory will not be considered within the 16 MB process heap space, using OpenGL could be an alternative.

Now my question is: Will OpenGL be fast enough to change and display the textures (my single frames) fast enough to achieve high frame rates of 15fps? I read an article saying that swapping textures too often will slow down OpenGL significantly. Did you guys got any experience about that? I don't want to spend time on getting OpenGL to run if you can already say that swapping fullscreen textures with 15fps is not feasible.

**Edit:**

I am now using a technique that uses the default Android NDK without making use of OpenGL. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724355/draw-high-res-animations-with-high-frame-rate-on-android#5101189).

Comment: You would only be changing textures once per frame.  That is not very often.

Comment: This sounds very much like you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Why do you *need* 30 uncompressed full-screen bitmaps in memory? Any reason you can't build your 30 frames into an .avi on your PC, include that as an asset in your .apk, then simply play it through a MediaPlayer?

Comment: The animation will be displayed as an overlay, that's why it has to be transparent. Unfortunately movies cannot be transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL performance will also depends on the devices you will use. But display only 30 textures at 15fps won't be a problem on most devices.

Take a look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) to start with OpenGL on Android. It is rather simple to achieve just a looping animation.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you rockeye, I'll start to dive into OpenGL. I will have to find out how to draw a texture. Already read that texture size has to be power of 2. Currently that's not the case, so I'll have to deal with that, too.

Answer (score 0):

There's no more need to make use of OpenGL for my case since 30 Frames can be loaded without exceeding the available space. As I found out running the `garbage collector` frees some memory that has been occupied during the loading of my 30 frames. It was not myself who created these objects that can bee freed since my code looks like that:

```
for (int i=0; i < 30; i++) {
  Bitmap b = "load480x320BitmapFromResources(i)";
  frames.add(b);
}
```

This previous code will exceed the heap space. But adding the line

```
System.gc();
```

within the loop allows loading all those resources. Strange, since I did not create objects by myself but I guess some internal Bitmap loading code of the Android framework did so.

[See also a more detailed description of this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724355/draw-high-res-animations-with-high-frame-rate-on-android/5101189#5101189)