# how to extract video frames and animate the bitmaps in android?

Tags: android

I started building the video editing app.Now i am able get the frames from current position
and i stored the bitmaps in arraylist.
I want display them in a view , which should look like
playing a trimmed video clip or kind of animation?
Please suggest me in this regard.

Comment: hmmm.... I think you should have benefits from the use of opengl...

Comment: what are other best approach with native API's?

Comment: nothing really performing I suppose. How many frames? How many fps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this to extract frame:

```
package com.example.androidmediametadataretriever;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 String uri = "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0007.mp4";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ImageView capturedImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.capturedimage);

  MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

  mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(uri);
  Bitmap bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(5000000); //unit in microsecond
  capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(bmFrame);
 }

}
```

Comment: i tried the same code,i set fps=30, and i captured the frames around 1 sec , nearly i got 34 bitmaps, which i stored in arraylist, now i wanted to display them one by one,plz let how can i achieve that?

Comment: I think you can start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724355/draw-high-res-animations-with-high-frame-rate-on-android

Comment: Thanks a lot, i look into that post

Comment: a simple approach: http://smartandroidians.blogspot.it/2010/02/animation-through-bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks for your kind support.

I tried with getFrameAt(time,MediaMetadataRetriever_OPTION_CLOSEST)
but i am getting null value.

Comment: try to use a different video source, maybe the error depends on the encoder used to compress the video

Comment: Here is my code:

for(int i=startTime ; i< endTime ; i+= fps) // fps=30
{
fBitmapList.add(mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime((i * 1000),MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST));
  if(i % 3 == 0){
    System.gc();
  }
}

Comment: as official documentation says: "A Bitmap containing a representative video frame, which can be null, if such a frame cannot be retrieved." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29

Comment: try with another video, try with a video caputured by a cam, one captured from a cell, so you can tell if it's a problem related to the encoder

Comment: Yes i tried with one good quality .mp4 file , now i am able to retrieve frames but not able to perceive because due to frame rate. The delay between drawing each bitmap i set around 30-33(msec).